# Red eye detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, face-detection

Project: Red eye detection

Description: I want to remove red-eye from images. I am not able to use face detector because, the faces in the images are not always frontal and also the images are of players with helmet. And the images may have many red eyes. Also, the lighting is not proper. I want to know how to detect the red eyes? I am searching for some proven studies. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just detect "red" areas?

Comment: This question does not show any effort on part of the OP and does not provide specific instances or examples of the problem.